# Android Contact Picker Has Different Behavior Across Versions

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-contacts

I am trying to get the email + display name of a single contact on android without requesting contact permission. I have a bit of code that works great on a device with Android 28

```kotlin
    // This gets called from a click listener on a UI component
    fun selectContact() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK).apply {
            type = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_TYPE
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent, 122)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        val phoneUri: Uri? = data?.data
        phoneUri?.let {
            val cursor: Cursor? = context?.contentResolver?.query(it, null, null, null, null)
            cursor?.let { c -> DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c) }
        }
    }
```

When I dump the cursor on my Android 30 device, it comes out empty every single time even though I am able to select a contact successfully in the contact picker. On my Android 28 device, the cursor has everything I need and works perfectly. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and was able to fix it by requesting the [READ_CONTACTS permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_CONTACTS) (https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

On my Android 10 (API 29) device more or less the same code like yours works fine. On my Android 11 (API 30) device the cursor is always empty. It also doens't matter if the old `onActivityResult` way is used or if `registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickContact())` is used to otain the initial URI.

It seems like the permission handling in that area got even more strict without explicitly mentioning.

**Edit:**
Also tried to add queries for the [package visibility](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility) with no success, only the permission fixed it for me.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: Yea the whole reason I wanted to make these changes in the first place was to remove our existing contact permission requirement, but I guess it is not possible anymore.